# To show decimal value of a variable inside <td></td> tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a variable dtot in my .cshtml file, which is declared as decimal as follows:

```
Nullable<decimal> dtot = 0;   
dtot = dtot + item.Qty;
<td style="text-align: center"><b>@dtot</b></td>
```

But not showing its decimal part on the page. For example: showing just 4 instead of 4.00

Comment: What is the type and value of `item.Qty`? Have you ever tried to use it's `Value` property instead like `@dtot.Value`?

Comment: `@string.Format("{0:0.00}", dtot)`?

Comment: `decimal?` is the type of item.Qty and value is 3.00, 1.00 like that.

Comment: `<td style="text-align: center"><b>@dtot.ToString("N2")</b></td> `

Comment: "not showing its decimal part", then what is it showing on the page? Nothing? A default value? Everything before the decimal? Have you tried with decimals that have something other than 0 as decimal part?

Answer (score 0):

```
@{Nullable<decimal>
    dtot = 0;
    dtot = dtot + item.Qty;
}

<td style="text-align: center"><b>@string.Format("{0:N2}", dtot)</b></td>
```

Using this will allow you to format the string correctly in this case to 2 decimal points.